# ASP .Net Core with MemoryCache

Tags: c#, memorycache

I use MemoryCache with ASP .Net Core. I want to save List<> in cache, but got strange problem.

1. Forming List;
2. Succesfully saved it in cache:

   ```
    TrySetEntity(typeof(SkvBase).Name, _wells, _cacheEntryOptions);

    public virtual void TrySetEntity(string key, IList<TEntity> createItem, MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheEntryOptions)
    {
        using var entry = _cache.CreateEntry(key);
        entry.SetOptions(cacheEntryOptions);
        entry.Value = createItem;
        _cache.Set(
        key,
        entry,
        new CancellationChangeToken(_resetCacheToken.Token));
    }
   ```
3. Cleared List!
4. Cache values was cleared too!! Why???

   ```
    public virtual TWell Get<TWell>(string key)
    {
        _cache.TryGetValue<TWell>(key, out var entry);
        return entry;
    }
   ```

Comment: `List<T>` is reference type. You saved a reference. So you can change content by reference.

Comment: Ooops!  And what i have to do? Main target is to decrease memory consumption, so i dont want to create additional lists.